# LEFT JOIN contar curtidas

Tags: mysql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas em MySQL (ela é mais complexa que o exemplo, simplifiquei):

```
CURSO:   id | nome
CURTIDA: id | id_curso
```

Toda vez que alguém curte um curso, alimenta a tabela CURTIDA

Agora, quando vou fazer o SELECT no curso, precisaria pegar a quantidade de curtida, fiz assim:

```
SELECT *, count(curtida.id) AS curtidas FROM curso 
LEFT JOIN curtida ON curtida.id_curso = curso.id
```

Mas não estou pegando o número certo de curtida... e se o curso não tem curtida, nem aparecendo está nesse select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa colocar um `GROUP BY` para agrupar os dados:

```
SELECT *, count(curtida.id) AS curtidas FROM curso 
LEFT JOIN curtida ON curtida.id_curso = curso.id
GROUP BY curso.id
```